# Creating a ComparableHashMap in Java

Tags: java

If I have this class:

```
public class ComparableHashMap<K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable>
        extends HashMap<Comparable,Comparable> implements Comparable {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(@NotNull Object o) {
        return 0; // just for simplicity of the question
    }
}
```

Why would this code have a `Incompatible types` error

```
Map<String, Comparable> retMap = new ComparableHashMap<String, Comparable>();
```

Whereas, this code below works:

```
Map<Comparable, Comparable> retMap = new ComparableHashMap<Comparable, Comparable>();
```

Comment: Because you extend `HashMap<Comparable,Comparable>` instead of `HashMap<K,V>`.

Comment: Oh, yeah you're right, how have I have forgotten X_X Thanks.

Comment: The type parameters are superfluous at object construction time and can be directly inferred by the compiler: All you need to write is `Map<String, Comparable> retMap = new ComparableHashMap();
`